# At what top income is the HST rebate set at 0?

Tags: canada, hst, limits

It appears that if a household has a total income greater than $166K (I wish), there is no rebate at all.  Is this a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.  More precisely, at **$166,700** there will be no HST transition benefit to a couple or family.